# How can I install extensions in PHP 7.4 (xampp 3.2.2)?

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension, mbstring

I want mbstring and fileinfo. There's no default `php.ini` file.
(And yes, I do have access to the \php\ext directory.)

Answer (score 0):

open the php.ini, remove the semicolon character (;) in front of the line below.

```
     extension = php_mbstring.dll
```

Comment: Hello, I recall saying I don't have the extension DLL or a "php.ini" file. So this will not work.